# iOS: Modify a font height, width, and spacing independently when creating PDF

Tags: ios, pdf, fonts

In an iOS app I need to use a specific font but each character needs to be taller, thinner, and the spacing closed up to fit correctly. Is it possible to stretch/squish a font programmatically?

Comment: *it possible to stretch/squish a font programmatically* - you can achieve such an effect in a PDF if you change the transformation matrix accordingly. For a tall but thin appearance, use a larger scaling for the y coordinate than for the x coordinate.

Comment: Did any of these answers answer your question? If so, could you please mark one as the solution? If not, could you indicate why not?

Comment: Your answer looked like the best bet. I tried to get the solution in but couldn't get it to work. I didn't have much of a chance because after working with it for about 20 minutes they decided not to put in the fix and work with a smaller font. It looks like a good solution I just never got the chance to see if it was.

Answer (score 1):

When you're adding text to a PDF file there are multiple ways to influence how the text is going to appear. The most generic way (and the way that might actually be sufficient for you) is to scale the text matrix:

```
void CGContextSetTextMatrix ( CGContextRef c, CGAffineTransform t );
```

As mentioned in the comment by @mkl, you can provide a matrix that will scale up in the Y direction while scaling down in the X direction. The effect will be that the letters are stretched out vertically and squished horizontally.

Normally I would expect you don't have to touch the spacing in that case, as spacing will be "squished" together just as the other characters.

Just in case that isn't sufficient, PDF actually does provide a way to change the spacing between characters too:

```
void CGContextSetCharacterSpacing ( CGContextRef context, CGFloat spacing );
```

While Apple's description talks about "additional space" to add between characters, the PDF specification and I suspect Apple's implementation as a result allows the spacing value to be both positive and negative. A negative value would have the effect of moving the characters closer together.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the best option would be to create your own custom font.

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately I don't know how to do it and I don't have time.

Comment: That's an awfully complicated thing and I don't think it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to change the kerning of your font (the space between the letters) and the thickness/thinness of the font, however you probably aren't able to edit the height of the font, unless you edit the bounding box the font is inside of to scale the letters differently.

You might also want to consider using a different font...or if you're REALLY hardcore you can edit the font yourself using photoshop/illustrator.

Comment: While the kerning would help, it wouldn't be enough.

Comment: Just curious, what font are you using?

Comment: We're using Andalé Mono